# Emission gloom with transparent background

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, transparency, emission

I'm trying to render a model using emission as it's shader and i'm using gloom node to get some glare of the emission, it looks fine in the viewport but as soon as i render it using cycles, the gloom is gone. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

In eevee, there is a feature called bloom you are using. But unfortunatley cycles doesn't have such an option , unless you use compositing. I recommend you watch some compositing tutorials on making lights glow in cycles. Here is the short summary of the process: select the objects you are using as a light, and then go to object properties: pass index to 2 on all of them (Remeber to set it to two on all the objects that have emmision shaders or are covering a lamp underneathe.).[image] Then in the render layers tab enable object index (Make sure you are in cycles to find this option.).[image] Then render your image, switch to the compositing tab, and follow the compositing setup in the image below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have added your effect in compositing, your problem probably is that you have checked off compositing here:

[image]